# Transaction fails during single-threaded execution

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently working on a Hibernate application. We are moving historical data off our file systems and into one of our databases. I simply read the contents of the csv files & commit those contents off to the db.

Unfortunately, I am running into the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Session/EntityManager is closed

I have tried multiple times to adjust my session.getTransaction() clause to no avail. When I research this error, the suggestions I get revolve around multithreaded applications. My application is single-threaded.

The code:

```
for (File d : archiveDirArray) {

            File[] fileList = d.listFiles();

            for (File f : fileList) {

                StringJoiner fileLocation = new StringJoiner("\\").add(parentDirectory).add(d.getName())
                        .add(f.getName());

                String fileName = f.getName();

                ConsumptionBuild[] cb = new ProcessFiles().readFileAndGenerateObjects(fileLocation.toString(), fileName,
                        d.getName());
                session.beginTransaction();//THIS IS LINE 67, WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN!!!

                for (ConsumptionBuild build : cb) {

                    session.save(build);
                }
                session.getTransaction().commit();

            }

        }//end of outer for loop
        session.close();

    }//end of main method
```

The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.beginTransaction(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:464)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:351)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at com.hibernate.main.HibernateMain.main(HibernateMain.java:67)
```

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix it?

Comment: Do you see where you call `session.close()`?

Comment: @Kayaman: that fall also first into my mind, but session close() is at right place - after outer foreach loop, but the tabs are badly formated.

Comment: This code snippet is embedded in my main method

Comment: How many iterations are you getting before the exception?

Comment: @Kayaman I get 1 iteration before it dies. It successfully commits to the db on the first iteration, but then gives me the error when it attempts to get the second session.getTransaction()

Comment: Then that suggests that committing the transaction also closes the session. I believe that's a matter of configuration rather than code.